# Как получить путь к dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

В `dll` пишу следующий код:

```
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Config\Settings.xml");
```

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` возврощает путь кем была загружена `dll`, т.е. к `.exe` файлу.

Как можно получить путь, где лежит `dll`, а не путь того кто эту `dll` вызвал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```